# How to instantiate an open serial connection

Tags: c#, serial-port

I need to take an already opened serial port connection (for example, COM1 connected to a device) and ask its baudrate, parity bit, stop bit, etc.

So, is there a way to take all the opened serial connections of the OS and instantiate them, like:

```
SerialPort myTestSP = "Windows.SerialPorts[1]";
int myTestBR = myTestSP.BaudRate;
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a supported way to do this. You can't open a device that's already open (serial ports do not allow sharing).

Programs such as [Portmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644) work by injecting a device driver in the serial port's stack, and even then I'm pretty sure it has to do it while the port is closed.

It's not possible to write such a driver in C#.

Comment: Ok, thanks.

What i´m trying to know are the settings used by an application to connect to a serial device (its baudrate, parity bit, etc). 
I´ve tried some serial monitors and sniffers, but none of them tell me that settings; i don´t want to monitor the traffic, i just want to know the settings used for the connection, so if you know any software that could tell me that, i would appreciate it.

Thanks again!

Comment: Portmon will do this. Just start Portmon and make sure it's listening on that COM port before starting the application. It'll tell you all the parameters it uses to connect.